# Will removing support for armv7s architecture still work fine for the iPhone 5 screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, xcode4.5, iphone-5

I am using Xcode 4.5 and using the base SDK, iOS6 and am porting my app for iPhone 5. Some of the libraries that I use for my app are still not built for armv7s architecture.

Will removing support for armv7s architecture still work fine for the iPhone 5 screen? Or, will I see black letterboxes? It works fine on the simulator though. Would like to know if anyone got a chance to test this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it should work fine. The deciding factor for whether your code will letterbox is the presence of a `Default-568h@2x.png` image file, not the architecture that the code is built for.