# The Google Analytics SDK for iOS isn't built for the armv7s architecture while instaling app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-analytics, xcode4.5

When i am trying to install my application on iPhone/iPad I am getting the following error. I am using new Xcode 4.5. What should I do to remove this error. I need to test my app on device.

file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/nishijain/Desktop/Backup SecondPrism/mobile/apps/SecondPrism/SecondPrism/Google Analytics SDK/libGoogleAnalytics.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to download the [latest version of the SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources), according to the [Changelog](http://feeds.feedburner.com/ga-dev-changelog-collection-ios) there is support for armv7s in Version 1.5.1.
If the error still happens try an older version of Xcode (probably Xcode 4.4.1) which has no clue of armv7s and throws no error.

EDIT:

This [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576144/will-removing-support-for-armv7s-architecture-still-work-fine-for-the-iphone-5-s) too:

In your Build Settings remove armv7s from Valid Architectures.

Comment: Thanks. Can't we remove armv7s from xcode 4.5 and tried for the same?

Comment: nope you can't actually remove armv7s because the sdk includes the iPhone 5 which runs the armv7s.

Comment: No I had updated the latest version but still getting same issue.Actually I checked this blog http://ashfurrow.com/fix-ios-6-sdk-linker-error.