# Incompatibility of Google Analytics with Google Maps iOS v 1.1.0

Tags: google-analytics, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to implementing the new version of GM for iOS and they doesn't work with GA library for iOS, anyone knows how to resolve this conflict?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SaxonDruce I got this error [link](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/8185/screenshot20130225at956.png), it seems a problem with armv7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting the same error messages as this question:

[Error while integrating Google Analytics SDK (GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta4) in my iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544891/error-while-integrating-google-analytics-sdk-googleanalyticsios-2-0beta4-in-my)

I don't think this is related to Google Maps.