# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 While adding pods from CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, xcode6, linker-errors

I am trying to use [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) into my App.

But immediately after adding it via CocoaPod i am getting this Error:

[image]

Previously I have GoogleMaps and GCM in my pod.

Now My Pod is look like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

How Can I resolve this Error:

***EDIT**

> This solve my problem:

If I run my existing project `X-Code 7` then I am not getting the Error.

But I want it to run in `Xcode 6.4` so I added older version of `GA` and that works fine with `X-Code 6.4.`

I have added manually the older `sdk` but if any one wants to add it Via `Cocoa-Pod` then Here is the way of doing it:

```
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '3.13.0'
```

Comment: Bro check out this.It might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605504/xcode-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-error-after-updating-cocoa-pods

Comment: did u added required framework for google analytics??

Comment: yes I have added 3 frameworks..

Answer (score 3):

Please remove "Other linker flag" which is set in build setting.
If it is set to -ObjC then please remove it and try to build again.

hope this works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544891/error-while-integrating-google-analytics-sdk-googleanalyticsios-2-0beta4-in-my

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605504/xcode-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-error-after-updating-cocoa-pods

Comment: check these links above bro

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me couple of times. To solve it run this two commands after adding your pods to the Podfile:

`pod deintegrate`

`pod clean`

Then:

`pod install`

If you find duplicated files xxxxxx 2.xx, in you Pod/ folder, try to move your project outside of Documents or Desktop, iCloud likes to mess the things if you work from different machines.

Comment: Thanks. This happened to me too. How often you got such error?

Comment: I solved this issue storing the projects outside of the "clouded" folders, like desktop or documents, due I work in two different macs with the same apple id, this thing was messing my work.

Comment: Thank you sir, worked perfectly.

I use iCloud between machines and ran into this problem.

Running `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` worked for me. There is no `pod clean` command in my current version but seems it was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This error often happens is accidentally importing the .m file instead of the .h

Comment: I am not importing any file..I just run `pod install` and build then I got this error