# Issue with Google Analytics via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, google-analytics, xcode6, cocoapods

I have searched the site and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084718/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-while-adding-pods-from-cocoapods) that has the same error, but all suggestions did not resolve my issue.

After reviewing Google's documentation, I did find this:

As of version 3.14 Google Analytics supports bitcode, which may cause compiler errors under Xcode 6. If you are still using Xcode 6 consider downloading v3.13.

Is it possible to set the pod to a specific version to keep the 3.13 versioning? Something similar to the syntax below:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics', '1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that resolved my issues using Google Analytics via a pod. I had to force the code base back to 3.13 when using Xcode 6. This solved the compile error with duplicate symbols.

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '3.13.0'
```